# Sphinx on Webfaction for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm looking to install [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/) and [thinking_sphinx](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/) on my basic shared hosting plan at [webfaction](http://www.webfaction.com/) so I can properly deploy my rails app. I'm positive webfaction supports this under my plan. I'm not anything near a linux guru in terms of skill level, but I know the basics.

How can I install Sphinx on my shared host without having sudo privileges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you posted this also at [webfaction](http://forum.webfaction.com/viewtopic.php?id=3802)

Putting the link here, for others to benefit ...

Answer (score 0):

Webfaction allows you to add your own gems without sudo.  Because it's shared hosting they install the gems required by passenger/your app into a non standard location (/home/< username >/webapps/< application_name >/gems/).  You'll need to add it to PATH in order to execute an installed gem in an ssh session and adding GEM_PATH/GEM_HOME can be useful as well.  As an example, without adding the right directory to your PATH your bash session wont find 'bundle' if you're using bundler.

Webfaction has a short writeup of installing gems by hand at http://docs.webfaction.com/software/rails.html#installing-gems

As a side note, I'm able to run a Rails3 app on webfaction using capistrano for deployment.  The bundle task installs the needed gems automatically.

PS - This is really a gem and webfaction issue.  You may want to modify your tags for this question.